# Can't get Bumblebee working on NVIDIA Corporation GK107M [GeForce GT 640M]

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee

**System:** hp pavilion dv7-7008tx laptop

Running `lspci | grep VGA` returns:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK107M [GeForce GT 650M] (rev ff)
```

I have installed all the bumblebee stuff:

```
sudo apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia primus nvidia-331
```

When I do `lshw -c video` I can only see my intel card, however, before I installed the nvidia-331 package I was able to see both the NVIDA and intel card.

```
  *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 09
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:46 memory:d3000000-d33fffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff ioport:5000(size=64)
```

I can however see my NVIDIA card in the "Additional Drivers" application.  The radio button is selected to use `Using NVIDIA binary driver -version 331.38 from nvidia-331 (proprietary, tested)`

Regardless of if I run `glxgears` or `optirun glxgears` I get the same frame rate of about 60 FPS.

Any ideas of how to fix this?  I was able to get bumblebee working on Fedora and openSUSE before on this machine so I am sure that I should be able to get it working but I can't seem to get it working with Ubuntu.

Comment: Already answered @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17196117/disable-vertical-sync-for-glxgears

Answer (score 0):

First of all to get much trusty results, glxspheres is better than glxgears. You can use "vblank_mode=0" for get higher results but it is all about v-sync. If you can run a program with optirun command there is no problem to worry about because your Nvidia card works.

You know that your Nvidia card is working but don't know working fine or not, for that compare glxspheres results between intel and nvidia card.

To install glxspheres:

Download VirtualGL (.deb) from: 
http://sourceforge.net/projects/virtualgl/files/VirtualGL/

Navigate to the folder containing the deb package and install it with

```
sudo dpkg -i VirtualGL_*.deb
```

Run glxspheres:

```
cd /opt/VirtualGL/bin/
```

`vblank_mode=0 ./glxspheres`

to run with nvidia card:

```
vblank_mode=0 optirun ./glxspheres
```

Note: vblank_mode=0 is for disable the v-sync and it spends much battery power. You don't need to use generally.